# php - inline font style for print statement?

Tags: php, inline-code

I know its possible to apply inline styles to echo statements but can this be done with print statements as well?

In my pagination I have links to previous and next records using the greater and less than symbols <> and a running count of the current record against the total number of records. e.g.

```
<
1/2
```

or

```
>
2/2
```

I have styled them in css but want to decrease the size of the count only. If I make changes to the css the font size for the previous and next links and count all change, I only want to target the count.

```
<div class="nextcard"><?php if($nextlink != ""){ print ($nextlink."<br/>".$next."/".$count); } ?></div>
```

I have tried :

```
<div class="nextcard"><?php if($nextlink != ""){ print 'style=font:50px' ($nextlink."<br/>".$next."/".$count); } ?></div>
```

But get syntax errors.

Comment: Of course it is possible (and if you don’t know how, go find a tutorial and learn basic PHP syntax) – but should not be doing it this way, inline styles are _yukky_ … you should rather be using a _class_ on that element and format it through your central stylesheet.

Comment: You haven't appended the string. Still, you will need to wrap it in a span

Comment: The only relevant thing currently is the "syntax errors". Fix those as nothing else matters until the syntax is valid syntax. And, if you do ask a question about such 1) search for the errors before posting for ideas 2) if posting, include the errors verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to add a class rather than inline styles. However, you have forgotten to append the string correctly.

Here is what I would personally do: (Note I replaced print with echo, TBH, there would be no different)

```
<div class="nextcard">    
   <?php
        if($nextlink != "")
            echo '<span class="mark">'.($nextlink."<br/>".$next."/".$count).'</span>'; 

    ?>
</div>
```

If you still want to style it inline, you should simply do:

```
<div class="nextcard">    
       <?php
            if($nextlink != "")
                echo '<span style="font-size:50px;">'.($nextlink."<br/>".$next."/".$count).'</span>'; 

        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! I put the span statement after the line break as the $nextlink variable is for the links to next and previous records. I only needed to target the count.